# Proper way to call overloaded method of embedded type in Go

Tags: types, go, embedding

I have an interface:

```
 package pkg
 type BaseInterface interface {
     func Nifty() bool
     func Other1() 
     func Other2()
     ...
     func Other34123()
 }
```

and a struct that implements it:

```
 package pkg
 type Impl struct {}
 func (Impl) Nifty() bool { ... }
```

Then along comes another struct which wants to embed the first and do it's own Nifty():

```
 package myOtherPackage
 import "pkg"
 type ImplToo struct {
     *pkg.Impl
 }
 func (it ImplToo) Nifty() bool { ... something else ... }
```

This is sort of like class inheretance with method override in an OOP language.   I want to know how to do the equivalent of implToo.super().Nifty() - that is, from the ImplToo Nifty() implementation, call the pkg.Impl Nifty() implementation.

What is the proper conversion to use on `it` so that  I can accomplish this?  Everything I try yields either unbounded recursion on ImplToo's Nifty(), or some compiler error such as:

`invalid type assertion: (&it).(BaseInterface) (non-interface type *it on left)`

... or many variations on that.

Comment: Have you tried `it.Impl.Nifty()`?

Comment: I did.  The problem is my actual "Impl" is really named something like "name.withADot" so the parse tells me the equivalent of `(type ImplToo has no field or method name)`   That seemed to make me think "OK, parens then", but it.(name.withADot).Nifty is parsed as an interface conversion, and back to the `non-interface type on left` error.

Comment: I don't understand. An identifier cannot contain a dot character. Please post your code.

Comment: But types do, since they are qualified by package name.  The dot is both a selector and package qualifier.   I've edited above to reflect what I'm talking about.  (And when you embed, the /type name is the field name/.   So how do you select it?  etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for;

```
 type ImplToo struct {
     pkg.Impl
 }

func (it ImplToo) Nifty() bool { return it.Impl.Nifty() }
```

Your use of pointers isn't consistent which is probably (not positive) part of your problem. If you want to make the embedded type a pointer then make your methods receiving type a pointer as well to avoid this problem.

If you want to explicitly use a method in the embedded type you reference it using the type where you would normally have a property name.

Comment: Please take note of my edit with the package prefix above.   Your ImplToo is not a valid declaration of a struct, because Impl is not defined.  It's pkg.Impl in the local package.  If it's pkg.Impl, I get `(type ImplToo has no field or method name pkg)`

Comment: @BadZen ok, I addressed your concern about the package. It doesn't effect the body of Nifty, only the stucts declaration.

Comment: Creating a new type that does not have an embed does not help - there are functions with the type's receiver that are /not/ 'overloaded' in this way, and I want to able to call those from the same expression.  You're basically saying "don't use embeds, compose everything".   That's great until I need to pass my type to some already-existing function that expects a BaseInterface.   Also consider having to call myImpl.In.A.Really.Long.Chain.Of.Subclasses()....

Comment: Put another way:  The ImplNotEmbed /won't even compile/ unless I provide "plumbing code" that maps other methods of the interface through to it's Impl.   That's unacceptable for large interfaces...

Comment: @BadZen ImplNotEmbed was just supposed to show you the difference in how you access the property of an embedded type vs a non embedded one. There isn't composition happening here. Just like in OOP if you want to override a method in a derived class AND use the base classes implementation you'll have to explicitly state that.... If you weren't overriding `Nifty` in `ImplToo` you could always just call `Nifty()` directly from an instance... It's called "ImplNotEmbed" because I'm not using embedding...

Comment: Huh?  Ok, I've edited the original post again to show you what I think is the problem with the second solution.  ImplNotEmbed needs to provide a ton of little funcs like `func (ine ImplNotEmbed) Other4() { ine.impl.Other4() }` just to compile.   See what I'm saying?

Comment: @BadZen I just deleted that code sample because it's confusing you... It was just supposed to illustrate the difference between accessing the method on an embedded type vs a normal property... the `ImplNotEmbed` example did not use the language feature 'embedding' at all. I'm quite sure the remaining code sample does what you're looking for. It is the closest thing to overriding a method in a derived class that Go has to offer. Take what you want from it, I assure you it works fine and is the correct way to accomplish things of this nature in Go.

Comment: Thanks, I understand how to not use embedding though.  I'm looking for an answer to my actual question, which does involve using embedding, as per the title of this thread.  I think it's a pretty clear question - you're offering me a way to not have to do what I want - ie. a workaround.

Comment: If the answer to my actual question is "you can't do that in Go", then that's fine, perfectly acceptable answer.

Comment: @BadZen again, your question is answered by my remaining code sample. It embeds the type `Impl` from the package `pkg` into the type `ImplToo` and then implements `Nifty()` with for a receiver of type `ImplToo` which simply calls `Impl`'s implementation of `Nifty()`. Read my comment above. If this doesn't make sense to you then you should re-think what you're trying to do. If you use my code above and `Impl` implements `BaseInterface` then I assure you `ImplToo` will do the same.

Comment: Well, now you've edited again and changed the answer.   Now you're removing my pointer (which is no bueno, since different "subclass instances" share a "super"), but it looks like this compiles even when it /is/ a pointer?  No need for reference/dereference?

Comment: Which totally works, but now I wonder - what happens if you have pkg1.Impl and pkg2.Impl?  Can't embed them both?    (I don't have that situation, but it's plausible)

Comment: @BadZen I think it works the same with or without the embed being a pointer. I just removed it because I suspected it might cause an error. You could probably embed from two different packages without compiler errors. I know for example, embedding types can have method name collisions and there are some rules for which is executed that you can find in the spec.

Comment: Cool, OK, calling this an answer then, TYVM

Answer (score 1):

What @evanmcdonnal said.  Your Nifty either need to take a pointer or not.  If you embed the pointer to `pkg.Impl` then your Nifty function needs to accept a struct pointer.  If your Nifty function doesn't take a pointer then your embeded type should not be a pointer.

Here is an embedded pointer that works.

·> cat main.go

```
package main

import (
    "cs/pkg"
    "fmt"
)

type ImplToo struct {
    *pkg.Impl
}

func (it *ImplToo) Nifty() bool {
    fmt.Printf("Impl.Nifty() is %t\n", it.Impl.Nifty())
    return false
}

func main() {
    i := new(ImplToo)
    fmt.Println(i.Nifty())
}
```

·> cat cs/pkg/test.go

```
package pkg

type BaseInterface interface {
    Nifty() bool
}

type Impl struct{}

func (i *Impl) Nifty() bool {
    return true
}
```

Output:

```
Impl.Nifty() is true
false
```

Comment: It's working just fine now with a pointer in the embed and not in the receiver, I think.   Does that mean there is an extra copy of the receiving interface going on?  It doesn't compile when both are pointers:  `ImplToo does not implement pkg.BaseInterface (Nifty method has pointer receiver)`