# Decorate specific method in Golang

Tags: go

I wondering what is a best way to decorate specific method in the structure. Let's say I have a big structure with many methods, I want to get my custom implementation similar to this structure and add some functionality to some specific method that contains complex logic:

```
type base struct {
    // ...
}

func (b *base) SpecificMethod() {
    fmt.Println("Some complex logic, must be reused")
}

func (b *base) Method() {
    fmt.Println("Reused as is")
}

// ... 77 methods that should be reused without any changes
```

Can I achieve the functionality similar to the following:

```
type MyType struct { // the same functionality as base except SpecificMethod() 
    b *base
}

func (mt *MyType) SpecificMethod() {
    fmt.Println("Additional logic")
    mt.b.SpecificMethod()
}

func (mt *MyType) Method() {
    mt.b.Method()
}

// 77 other methods... :(
```

- MyType and base should satisfy the same interface
- base is unchangeable

**but without the need to override all other 77 methods?**

I hope I explained myself well, any suggestions are welcome.
Thanks!

Comment: Use [embedded fields](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types) instead. eg: `type MyType struct { *base }`.

Comment: Thanks, but how in MyType. SpecificMethod can I reuse base.SpecificMethod() if I'll use embedded fields?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proper way to call overloaded method of embedded type in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29955093/proper-way-to-call-overloaded-method-of-embedded-type-in-go)

Comment: You could read up starting with what I linked to. Or you could copy-paste from the linked answer.

Comment: Actually, I can use combination of both approaches: 
type MyType struct {
 base
 b *base
}.
Seems little bit strange...

Comment: @Marc Unfortunately, the question you linked doesn't help. MyType should satisfy the same interface.

Comment: It does, the method set of `MyType` includes the method set of its embedded fields. Check the linked question again, I picked a better one. Then I recommend you read up on embedded fields and how they work.

Comment: Or try [this playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/OH7jFQXizon) for the basics.

Comment: @Marc Yes, the second link seems like gives an answer: I can use mt.base.SpecificMethod() instead of mt.b.SpecificMethod().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `base` as an embedded field in `MyType` and overload the specific method.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type base struct {
    value int
}

func (f *base) Print() {
    fmt.Println(f.value)
}

func (f *base) Add(val int) {
    f.value += val
}

type MyType struct {
    *base
}

func (b *MyType) Print() {
    b.value += 10
    b.base.Print()
}

func main() {
    b := MyType{&base{1}}
    b.Add(5)
    b.Print()
}
```